# Selenium Chrome Mismatch

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver

I desperately want to solve my coding conundrum which remain unfixed for 5 days. The goal is to crawl an website by using Selenium Package. My code is below.

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options    

chrome_options = Options()   
chrome_options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)    
chrome_options.add_argument('--headless=new')  
chrome_options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')

service = Service()   
browser = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)   
browser.get('law.go.kr/')

time.sleep(5)
```

The result is below. `InvalidArgumentException` is shown. In my opinion, 'chrome=122.0.6261.111' is the key point.

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument (Session info: chrome=122.0.6261.111)

Stacktrace:

#0 0x5745bb24dec3 \<unknown\>

#1 0x5745baf45b37 \<unknown\>

#2 0x5745baf2d4df \<unknown\>

#3 0x5745baf2b863 \<unknown\>

#4 0x5745baf2bdaa \<unknown\>

#5 0x5745baf4849e \<unknown\>
```

I guess the reason why the exception pops out is Chrome version mismatch.

> My Chrome Version : 122.0.6261.112

> My Chrome-Webdriver Version : 122.0.6261.111

So I've tried several different ways, but not worked.

My attempts are below. First, Using webdriver-manager code.

```
from selenium import webdriver    
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService    
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver=webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get('law.go.kr')
```

But, it not worked, either. Error message is below. `The point is 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'`. I have no idea why it happens.

```
determined_browser_version = ".".join(determined_browser_version.split(".")\[:3\])

latest_release_url = (self.\_latest_release_url

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument
```

The reason for above exception is: `.get` method expects a fully qualified URL, not a string.

Change this:

```
browser.get('law.go.kr/')
```

TO:

```
browser.get('https://law.go.kr/')
```